# Apache: Redirect domain to other domain with appended querystring

Tags: apache, redirect, apache-config

I want example.se to redirect to example.com?lang=swe

It works fine with this apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.se
    ServerAlias *.example.se
    Redirect permanent / http://example.com/?lang=swe
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that this breaks if there is something else after the domain, ex: example.se/page1 should redirect to example.com/page1?lang=1 but with the setup above it redirects to example.com?lang=swepage1.

Is there a way to do this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it should be something close to this:

RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.+)$ http://example.com/$1?lang=swe

Comment: Perfect! Used (.*) instead though to make still work for only the domain example.se