# apache RedirectMatch that appends a querystring

Tags: apache, wamp

I am trying to set up a redirect in Apache that adds a querystring.  I do not think I want to use RewriteRule because the target is a different webserver.  I have something like this now:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5:4039>
    ServerName localhost.redirect
    RedirectMatch (.*) http://otherserver.com$1?originalHost=127.0.0.5
</VirtualHost>
```

This works in that requests to `http://127.0.0.5:4039/foo` are redirected to `http://otherserver.com/foo?originalHost=127.0.0.5`.  The problem is that `http://127.0.0.5:4039/foo?another=value` is redirected to `http://otherserver.com/foo?originalHost=127.0.0.5` as well, I want something like `http://otherserver.com/foo?another=value&originalHost=127.0.0.5` where the original querystring is preserved.

Any tips on how to do this?  I'm running on WAMP, and not very good at this apache thing.

There is a related question here where someone has a redirect where the target includes a querystring: [Apache: Redirect domain to other domain with appended querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355655/apache-redirect-domain-to-other-domain-with-appended-querystring).  They are not trying to append a querystring though, just set one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to have to bite the bullet and use mod_rewrite. It's got a flag for appending an existing query string to a target query string. You'll replace the `RedirectMatch` with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherserver.com$1?originalHost=127.0.0.5 [L,QSA,R=302]
```

It'll look pretty much the same, and it'll redirect with a 302 (you can replace with 301 if you'd rather it be permanent), except with this, an existing query string will get neatly appended to `?originalHost=127.0.0.5`.